# LARAVEL PASSPORT очистить старый oauth_refresh_token

Tags: laravel, passport

После выполнения выхода - отмена Аутентификации (например выход из админки) необходимо удалить старые записи Passport в таблицах oauth_access_tokens, а ТАКЖЕ и в oauth_refresh_token.
Во всех материалах по Passport(видео и т.д.) нигде нет про рефреш токены.

Answer (score 0):

Поэтому сам поковырял и сделал так (возможно это поможет кому-либо):
`

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
            $token->delete();
        });
        $table = DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')->where('access_token_id', auth()->user()->tokens[0]->id)->delete();
        return  response()->json('Вышли из админ-панели успешно', 200);
    }
```

`